# Azure Library for Lucene.net Error. File Not Found After write.lock created

Tags: azure, lucene.net

When executing the following code in an empty azure container, I get file not found error (segments.gen; The specified blob does not exist.).

```
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(account, "audiobookindex"); // <-- audiobookindex is the name of the blog storage container on my Azure account

// Create the index writerIndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
```

It seems to be failing on the OpenInput inside the Azure Library for Lucene.net assembly. However I don't understand while it's even calling that method. Would think it would just try to create it.

Also, the assembly and code IS hitting the container because it creates a write.lock file that I can see in the container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: RESOLVED: found the reference that I needed to set the debugger to NOT stop on FileNotFound exceptions because Lucene.Net uses File not found and read past EOF exceptions as part of normal operations.

Comment: For what it's worth, Thermous, the chap who wrote AzureDirectory, mentions this in the Q&A here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538/view/Discussions#content

Comment: I got the same issue and spent whole day to solve it. I finally found that I also set to stop on FileNotFound exception. :(

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216033313/http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx) should solve this problem. The examples in market are developed with older apis and older framework version etc. I found the above solution which works fine! No need of putting interfering with debugger ;)